# what could be the cause of the error below while Installing the Required Karaf Features?

Tags: python, php, html, sql, linux

I'm installing Karaf Features on Ubuntu 20.04 using the Islandora Manual installation and i'm getting the error below.....

frazer@frazer-Islandora:~$ sudo /opt/karaf/bin/client feature:install activemq-blueprint
[sudo] password for frazer:
Logging in as karaf
Error executing command: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=activemq-blueprint; type=karaf.feature; version="[5.15.11,5.15.11]"; filter:="(&(osgi.identity=activemq-blueprint)(type=karaf.feature)(version>=5.15.11)(version<=5.15.11))" [caused by: Unable to resolve activemq-blueprint/5.15.11: missing requirement [activemq-blueprint/5.15.11] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=activemq; type=karaf.feature; version="[5.15.11,5.15.11]"]

Comment: missing requirement [activemq-blueprint/5.15.11]

Comment: [I am not sure, but this may help](https://svn.apache.org/repos/infra/websites/production/activemq/content/5.7.0/osgi-integration.html)